# .gitignore troubles with subdirectories

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

I am having trouble with this gitignore file for my Unity project. I want to exclude my assets folder except for the subdirectories under the "Include Me" entry.

All files under Assets/Scripts and Assets/Scenes are being added to my repository, but not the Assets/Cards... subdirectories. I really can't figure out why one include/exclude pattern is working but the others aren't.

How can I make this file work to include those other subdirectories?

```
# =============== #
# Unity generated #
# =============== #
Temp/
Library/
Builds/
Assets/*

# ============ #
# Include Me   #
# ============ #

!Assets/Scripts
!Assets/Scenes/
!Assets/Cards/Miniatures/Resources/*
!Assets/Cards/Miniatures/Resources/
!Assets/Cards/Spells/Resources/
!Assets/Cards/Spells/Resources/*
```

Answer (score 1):

This question have been answered many times before here on SO... E.g.

**[.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)**

Answer (score 0):

What Caio said is that should work. If I am not wrong

```
# =============== #
# Unity generated #
# =============== #
Temp/
Library/
Builds/
Assets/*
Assets/Cards/*
Assets/Cards/Miniatures/*
Assets/Cards/Spells/*

# ============ #
# Include Me   #
# ============ #

!Assets/Scripts
!Assets/Scenes/
!Assets/Cards/
!Assets/Cards/Miniatures
!Assets/Cards/Miniatures/Resources/
!Assets/Cards/Spells/
!Assets/Cards/Spells/Resources/
```